# Are these magnetic field lines drawn correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetostatics

I was asked to reason out if the following magnetic field lines are correctly described or not.

**(A)** (The blue line is a solenoid and the dark ones are the field lines)

[image]

**My answer**:I think these are incorrect as there is bound to be some fringing at the ends of the solenoid.

**Book's answer**:

> Wrong. Field lines due to a solenoid at its ends and outside cannot be so completely straight and confined; such a thing violates Ampere's law. The lines should curve out at both ends, and meet eventually to form closed loops.

**My question**:How does Ampere's circuital law come into the picture and **why is it being violated?**

**(B)**  (picture shows magnetic field lines pointing from N to S)

[image]

**My answer**:Incorrect.Same reason as above.

**Book's answer**:

> Wrong. Magnetic field lines between two pole pieces cannot be precisely straight at the ends. Some fringing of lines is inevitable. Otherwise, Ampere's law is violated. This is also true for electric field lines.

**My question**:Once again,how does Ampere's circuital law come into the picture and **why is it being violated**?

Comment: Which book is it ?

Comment: It's published by an organization called NCERT for high school students in India